# What is the best practice for Ruby on Rails 3 layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3 offer `application.html.erb` as a layout template. However, whenever you send request to access a controller view, the content of `application.html.erb` will be loaded again. This seems not efficient, since header, navigation, footer only need to be loaded once.

In addition, when you need to have a javascript code executed in `$(window).load` for `application.html.erb` and another js method executed in `$(window).load` for `<controller>.html.erb`, this will mess up. I think the reason is that `$(window).load` can only execute once for each page.

So I wonder what's the best Layout practice for Rails 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 includes [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), which will only reload the body of your website when a link is clicked, instead of reloading all of the assets like javascript and CSS. If you want to fine tune what gets loaded further, you can take a look at [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax), but I think for most applications Turbolinks will be sufficient.